# LINQ OrderBy ThenByDescending using data from two tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-ce

I have a table `Student` with these columns:

```
ID (PK, bigint, not null)
Height (int, not null)
IQ (int, not null)
SchoolId (bigint, not null)
```

and a table `School` with columns:

```
ID (PK, bigint, not null)
Charter (bit, not null)   -- 1 means charter, 0 means not charter
```

I also have a method

```
private static IEnumerable<IStudent> SortStudentList(IEnumerable<IStudent> students)
{
    return students.OrderBy(s => s.Height).ThenBy(s => s.IQ);
}
```

and this works great. Now however, I need to also sort by Charter. In English, "sort by ascending height, then by descending Charter (get Charter schools first), then by ascending IQ"

Something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<IStudent> SortStudentList(IEnumerable<IStudent> students)
{
    return students.OrderBy(s => s.Height).ThenByDescending(s => s.GetCharterStatus).ThenBy(s => s.IQ);
}
```

The entity (I'm using Entity Framework) `Student` does have a link to `School` via

```
public class Student, IStudent
{
     ...
      [Index(IsUnique = true)]
      public long SchoolId { get; set; }
     ...
}

public interface IStudent
{
      ...
      long SchoolId {get;set;}
      ...
 }
```

Curiously, when I look at the relationship using SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox, I don't see SchoolId list as a foreign key, but rather under the "Indexes" folder of Student table where it appears as

```
IX_SchoolId (Unique)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Charter school part of the query and have tried various things. Do I need to somehow do a join?

Let me know if I can clarify or provide more info. I'm using SQL Server CE and Entity Framework although I suspect that's not relevant to the question.

Thanks,
Dave

P.S. The data is made up to protect company secrets but the relationships are the same.  I have no opinion whatsoever about the relationship between height, IQ, and charter school status :)

Comment: Do you have the `Student -> School` foreign key mapped in EF?  For example, is there a property `School` on the `Student` entity?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response dana.  I've added explanation to my question.  I couldn't format in a comment.  Student Entity has a SchoolId property, not a School property.  Not sure if that's a foreign key or not.  See updated question for details.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another way, by adding an extension method:

```
public static short GetCharterStatus(this IStudent student, )
{
   return schools.First(school=> school.ID == student.SchoolId).Charter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Abdullah.  In this particular case, this was the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Charter school part of the query and have tried various things. Do I need to somehow do a join?

Yes, but there are a few ways that you can go about doing this, depending if you are using an ORM or not.

**The SQL-based approach**

If using plain SQL, you would need to join the two tables to pull all the data that you needed. The query might look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Students.*,
    Schools.Charter           
FROM 
    Students
INNER JOIN 
    Schools ON Students.SchoolId = Schools.Id
```

This would return a collection of Students along with their "Charter School Designation", which might look like this :

```
public class StudentWithSchoolType
{
     // Properties from Student
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public int Height { get; set; }
     public int IQ { get; set; }
     // Properties from Schools
     public bool Charter { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you already have these properties on an interface for `IStudent` it might look more like :

```
public class StudentWithSchoolType : IStudent
{
     // Student Properties inherited from IStudent

     public bool Charter { get; set; }
}
```

If you will always be performing this, you could include it on the interface as well, but your needs may vary.

Once you have that data, you can simply access either the Student or School data that you need to order by independently as the necessary fields should be

```
private static IEnumerable<IStudent> SortStudentList(IEnumerable<IStudent> students)
{
    return students.OrderBy(s => s.Height)
                   .ThenByDescending(s => s.Charter)
                   .ThenBy(s => s.IQ);   
}
```

**The ORM-based approach**

If you are using an ORM like Entity Framework and have a relationship between these two tables (i.e. School property on Student), then you can pull this data in via an `Include()` method call when you make your pull from the database:

```
// This will populate the School property of the Student with any 
// properties it has
var students = YourContext.Students
                          .Include("School")
                          .ToList();
```

This would simplify your query as you could then just use:

```
private static IEnumerable<IStudent> SortStudentList(IEnumerable<IStudent> students)
{
    // Notice the use of s.School.Charter
    return students.OrderBy(s => s.Height)
                   .ThenByDescending(s => s.School.Charter)
                   .ThenBy(s => s.IQ);   
}
```

If you don't already have a `School` object, but have the key, then you'll just need to add one as follows to your `Student` entity:

```
public class Student
{
    // Your Student properties here

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public long SchoolId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual School School  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rion.  I've updated the question in response to another comment to make clear that Student entity has a SchoolId property and NOT a School property.  I'm not sure what that makes the relationship between School and Student to be. I think changing the entity definitions and db schema might be problematic.

Comment: @Dave You can add the `School` navigation property without changing the database schema. It's just a reference expression of the foreign key. Highly recommended.

Comment: Since you already have the relationship within your database, you'll just need to reference the appropriate foreign key and add the property (that will be populated) to your `Student` entity (which will be populated via the above `Include()` call). I've added a small snippet above that demonstrates roughly how that works.

Comment: Thanks Rion and Gert,  Any downsides to this?  I'm somewhat reluctant to change the entities.  It's a large code base and out in the field.  There could (for example) be some report module that uses all members of Student entity to display data.  Now, I'd have an extra column.  I'm not saying that's the case, only that there may be unintended consequences.  Is there a way to just use the SchoolId? And what do you call the relationship when there is a SchoolId member and not School? Compact Toolbox made it seem like an "Index", not a foreign key (see my question for details).  Thanks!

Comment: It won't really affect much, and it's important to remember that the `School` property will only be populated when the `Include()` method is called. Otherwise, it'll be null. This won't really change anything within your database either (in terms of adding another column), as this property would only exist "in code" and would serve as a placeholder for when you wanted to pull in more data via an `Include()` call.

Comment: As far as the Index issue, since this was a key, it's likely just being indexed as keys often are. I haven't worked with CE enough to know all of it's ins/outs regarding that.

Comment: Actually, I'm stupid. I neglected to notice the `[Index]` attribute that was present in your model itself. This will tell SQL to build an index for a given column, in this case, the `SchoolId` one. If you want it to recognize something as relying on a foreign key, you can use the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to handle that.

Comment: Thanks Rion, I'll have to digest this.  I may not have made clear that Student (and School) derive from interfaces and it is those interfaces that are passed around to SortStudentList.  I've updated question to more explicitly call this out.  Perhaps more importantly, where the code populates students is with a call to context.Set<T>().ToList().  I believe this is so they can have the same code populating all entity types. I'll have to think about how to treat the Student entity differently.

Comment: Thanks Rion,  If I were starting from scratch, I would use your ideas.  But given the existing architecture, it turned out to be easier (in my case) to use Abdullah's answer.